# How to delete a column of an excel document created by exporting an access subform?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to delete a column from a excel file created by exporting an access subform.

I use the following vba code to perform the export. The exported file contains are five column.

```
Private Sub CmdExporter_Click()
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSelectAllRecords
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy
    Dim xlapp As Object
    Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    With xlapp
        .Workbooks.Add
        .ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= _
        False
        .Cells.Select
        .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        .Visible = True
        .Range("o1").Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Can someone help me adjust the code in order to be able to delete the last column(5th column) as the excel document gets exported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Range.Delete` to delete cells.  A refined version of your sub is:

```
Private Sub CmdExporter_Click()
    ' Create Excel app
    Dim xlapp As Object
    Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    With xlapp
        .Visible = True ' show Excel app

        ' Create new workbook in Excel
        Dim xlWorkbook As Object
        Set xlWorkbook = .Workbooks.Add
    End With

    ' Get a reference to the workbook's first sheet
    Dim xlSheet As Object
    Set xlSheet = xlWorkbook.worksheets(1)

    ' Copy access data - done just before paste to reduce chance of clipboard being changed before paste
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSelectAllRecords
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy

    xlSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False ' Paste the data
    xlSheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit ' Auto fit column width

    ' Option 1: Delete last column
    xlSheet.UsedRange.Columns(xlSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count).EntireColumn.Delete

    ' OR Option 2: Delete 5th column
    xlSheet.UsedRange.Columns(5).EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many examples online showing how to [delete an Excel column using Access VBA](https://www.google.com/search?q=delete%20excel%20column%20using%20access%20vba).  Which one is best for you depends on what you have and what you're trying to do.

Without having more specific information about your data or desired 'end-goal', I'd suggest that you may find it easier to use one of the methods specifically intended for exporting data from Access to Excel.

For example, a single line of code:

`DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Table1", "x:\myOutputFile.xlsx", True, "myWorksheet"`

...creates (or updates, if it exists and is closed) an Excel file `x:\myOutputFile.xlsx`, creating (or updating if it exists) a sheet called `myWorksheet`, with the contents of table `Table1`.  (For a partial dataset, you could specify a query name instead of table name.)

---

### More Information:

- Microsoft Docs : [**`DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` method** (Access)](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/access.docmd.transferspreadsheet)

Comment: Further recommended reading: "**How to create a [mcve]**" as well as "[ask]" and "[Writing the Perfect uestion](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/)".